# AWS Lambda functions some times does not work

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an AWS Lambda function which is internally calling multiple Lambda functions based on input. It can call multiple internal functions or same function multiple times which is completely based on input payload.

I am using 'Invoke' to call internal functions. It's all working as required. Sometimes internal functions are never called and caller lambda times out after the configured time out seconds. Sometimes it starts working after redeployment or increase in memory/time out and redeploy.

Has anyone faced this and is there any solution ? As it fails some times, not sure of what is the cause. Please suggest.

Comment: Might you be approaching the limit of 1000 concurrent Lambda functions?